# Convert a date and time string in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Is there any way to convert "A date and time string in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS” using legacy SQL syntax or standard SQL syntax in BigQuery.

For eg. "November 9, 2017" to 2017-11-09 00:00:00

Comment: You mean like strtotime in PHP? How about a stored procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT PARSE_DATE('%B %d, %Y', 'November 9, 2017')
```

result is

```
f0_  
2017-11-09
```

or you can use

```
#standardSQL
SELECT PARSE_DATETIME('%B %d, %Y', 'November 9, 2017')
```

which returns

```
f0_  
2017-11-09T00:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks @mikhail.
How about this kind of string "Fri, 31 Aug 2018 13:00:57 +0000". 
I Tried below, but its not working
SELECT PARSE_DATETIME('%a,%d %b %Y %E#S' , 'Fri, 31 Aug 2018 13:00:57 +0000')

Comment: sure - ask more when needed :o)

Comment: Please help me in my above comment.

Comment: Sure, I meant - feel free to post new question and I will be glad to answer. Format of comments does not allow providing quality answer  - so as I said  - post new question please

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server (2005, 2000, 7.0) does not have any flexible, or even non-flexible, way of taking an arbitrarily structured datetime in string format and converting it to the datetime data type.

By "arbitrarily", I mean "a form that the person who wrote it, though perhaps not you or I or someone on the other side of the planet, would consider to be intuitive and completely obvious." Frankly, I'm not sure there is any such algorithm.